# Nested Query Compatibility in Elastic Search 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have below payload in my REST call (POST) and its working fine Elastic search 2.1.1 but not in ES 5.6.7

```
{"from":0,"size":5,"sort":[{"releasedDate":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"query_string":{"query":{"query":"demo demo*","defaultOperator":"and"}}}}
```

In ES 5.6.7, I got below exception

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
        {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 96
        }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[query_string] unknown token [START_OBJECT] after [query]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 96
},
"status": 400
```

}

Anyone have any idea why the payload is not working in ES 5.6.7 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ES 5.6.7 you need to write it like this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 5,
  "sort": [
    {
      "releasedDate": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "demo demo*",
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```

Find the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

Comment: No i got the below response from the REST service                                            {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [defaultOperator]","line":1,"col":140}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[query_string] query does not support [defaultOperator]","line":1,"col":140},"status":400} . If i remove the  "defaultOperator" it works

Comment: Any reason or is there any official documentation from ES 5.6 ??

Comment: Updated @Val's answer. It should be `default_operator` and not `defaultOperator`

Comment: Thanks @NishantSaini

Comment: @ValThank you both for your answer. But i am bit wondering that how the same query is still working in ES 2.1.1 any hint fellows ??

Comment: What's probably happened is that ES2 was more lenient on non well-formed queries. It was already wrong back then, but ES would apply some corrections in order to make your query work. Now ES is more strict, which is a good thing, I reckon.

Comment: @Val - I think so. Thanks a lot :)